# Call a function of an another class (protocol)

Tags: ios, swift, function, protocols

I have a Slide out navigation panel (menu) and an another "menu" on my first page.

[image]

Slide out Menu:

- Index
- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4

On Index:

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4

So the user have access to the pages from the Index or by Sliding (or tap on Icon Menu) to have the menu.

But I have an error: I go to page 1 from the Index, I tap on the Icon Menu to slide out the Menu I tap on index, I go to page 1 again from the Index, and here if I tap again on the Icon Menu, I get error: SIGBRT
 (something like that)

I did some breakpoints:

On this line: `self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController(‌​)!)`

And one in the function `pushViewControllerInStack`

And when I do maniplations, my app read this line `self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController(‌​)!)` but it don't go in the function.

So my view `lost the access` of the function, but I don't know why and how to fix the issue.

There's a lot of code, you can find a git repository here: https://github.com/Vkt0r/SlideOutSideBarTest

the error:

```
2015-10-28 09:00:33.038 Solutis[477:5075] -[Solutis.NosOffresViewController menuNosOffresTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff5caf464e0
2015-10-28 09:00:33.045 Solutis[477:5075] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Solutis.NosOffresViewController menuNosOffresTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff5caf464e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3b1f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111268deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3ba58d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f307f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f307b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010fdf31fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001101d5247 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010fdf31fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ff57504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ff577d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ff5794b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 690
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ff56906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fe5daa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fe5e691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fe10752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010fdebfcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2de0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2d3fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2d3483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2d2e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011485bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010fdf1676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  Solutis                             0x000000010f1b892d main + 109
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111d8092d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: You should really post the whole error. "SIGBRT (something like that)" will not help anyone solve your issue. Also, it's unlikely that someone will go to your github repo and look through all of your code and try to find the error. I would post the block of code (not just the one line above) where you invoke these actions.

Comment: When you get SIGABRT, Xcode should show the Debug navigator (on the left side of the Xcode window). Select all the lines of the stack trace, copy them, and paste them into your question.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson I just posted the error code, I think it's useless because i'll post 80% of my app

Comment: @robmayoff I just posted the error code

Answer (score 0):

You linked the action with the bar item
[image: You linked the action with the bar item]

And you commented it:
[image: And you commented it]

So it would crash when you try to open the menu at that page.

Comment: Thanks for your response,if I don't comment: the app go to this line: `delegate?toggleLeftpanel()` but it doesn't go to the function, it doesn't work.

Comment: You could just comment that line but not the method

Comment: Yes but I just comment it because this way doesn't work so I'm trying other ways, I want to open the slide out navigation panel when I tap on it, but the app crash, I don't understand, first time it work but at the second time it doesn't

Comment: you need to make sure the delegate is still there when you get it from storyboard

Comment: How to see that ? I did some test: at first time the icon menu is working because it's the button under the function: pushviewcontrollerinstack, but at the second time, it's the icon menu of the storyboard and not of the pushviewcontroller because the function wasn't executed. (sorry for my english)

Comment: you can print delegate in the ibaction, and you will see the delegate is nil

Comment: At first time and second time the value is nil

Comment: I just tested something with my first page "Accueil", I printed the delegate at first time it wrks, but when I go back to the Accueil from my menu I lost my delegate it's equal to null