# delegate equals to nil

Tags: ios, swift, function, delegates

I have a problem with my iconMenu it doesn't work, I can only slide to open my menu, I have this error only I change page from my first page ("Accueil") instead of using my slide out menu. Yes because I have a slide out menu and links on my first page, like that:

[image]

So when I use links of my first view, my iconMenu is like disabled, it's because here:

```
@IBAction func menuNosOffresTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.toggleLeftPanel!()
}
```

My app can't go at the function `toggleLeftPanel` here: [Call a function of an another class (protocol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371860/call-a-function-of-an-another-class-protocol/33387084?noredirect=1#comment54568707_33387084) someone told me that the problem could came from my delegate.

I did some test, I lost my delegate when I use first page links and when I use my Slide out menu.

App is here: https://github.com/Vkt0r/SlideOutSideBarTest

So I think to get access to toggleLeftPanel, I have to get my delegate.

Comment: Have you added the "All Exceptions" breakpoint? This will make the debugger stop on the line where the exception is happening. Add the all exceptions break point like this: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/add_exception_breakpoint.png

Comment: No but I used breakpoints and I see from where the problem come from, but I don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your NosOffresViewController is missing the menuTapped action.

Comment: Sorry bad upsate, the problem don't came frome the name

Comment: I have looked at your code. What if you had a viewcontroller for the left menu and then a viewcontroller for the main menu with all the actions connected correctly - and then do not change these. In the main viewcontroller you can add in a container view controller, and then based on any menu changes from the left view controller, you update the container view in the menu view controller.